# Why does "que ça" mean "at it" in this instance?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, comparatifs

I read the following sentence in a book:

> *C'est vraiment difficile de réussir dans ce milieu-là. Et puis, je ne suis pas si douée **que ça**.*

My translator translated it to:

> It’s really difficult to succeed in that field. And I'm not that
>   talented **at it**.

However, I don't understand why "que ça" which should mean "but that" is instead used to mean "at it" in this instance. Shouldn't the second sentence use "avec ça" instead? (*see below*)

> *C'est vraiment difficile de réussir dans ce milieu-là. Et puis, je ne suis pas si douée **avec ça.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Je ne suis pas **si** douée **que ça***

just means:

> I'm not **that** talented.

Comment: I thought "si" means "that".

Comment: Here *pas si xxx que ça* translates to *not that xxx*. It is possible to drop *que ça* without substantially changing the meaning: *Je ne suis pas si douée*.

Comment: Short, concise answer. The bolding really helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't. A literal translation of “*Et puis, je ne suis pas si douée que ça.*” could be “And then, I am not as talented as that”. “*Pas si [adjective] que ça*” is an idiom that means “not very [adjective]”. In English, you can express a similar degree of “not very” by “not that [adjective]”.

“*Je suis douée*” on its own means “I am talented” (in general), and “*je suis douée pour …*” means “I am talented at …”. In the context you're quoting, it's implied in French that the statement is qualified: it's about the specific thing mentioned in the previous sentence (succeeding in that environment). In English the unqualified statement feels a bit broader, so it's more natural to say “talented at it”. In French, you could say “*je ne suis pas si douée que ça pour ça*”, but it feels a bit awkward, and it's also repetitive due to the double use of “*ça*”, so we would omit “*pour ça*”.

You can say “*je suis douée avec ça*”, but only to express talent *with* some specific tool or method. Here it's about talent to achieve an objective, so the correct preposition is “*pour*”, not “*avec*”.

Answer (score 1):

"Je ne suis pas si douée que ça" could means :

> I'm not talented as much as you think.

Or

> I'm not talented like others can be.

It's generally the answer of the sentence: "You are talented!"

This means you compare yourself with the talent of others people and you think that you don't have enough talent.